# How to make <CSS transition> work for external-svg-sprites and css-variable?

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, svg-animate, svg-sprite

TL;DR

Having created `symbol-svg-sprite` and inserting its fragment using `svg+use`, I want to use `css-variables` inside #ShadowDOM for SVG `presentation attributes` to change for example `stroke-width="0"` in `stroke-width="5"`, and the `transition property` must work, the problem is that the `stroke-width` values work at any event (:hover :active :focus) and `transition` does not.

---

### External SVG sample

```
<svg style='display:none;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id='symbol-id' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 23 20">
        <path style='transition-duration: var(--custom-duration); transition-property: var(--custom-property);' stroke="var(--custom-stroke)" stroke-width="var(--custom-stroke-width)" fill="cyan" d="long..."
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

### Insert SVG+USE

```
<svg>
    <use class="use-class" xlink:href="../transition-error.svg#symbol-id"></use>
</svg>
```

### Applied CSS style

```
svg
    outline 1px solid black
    width 250px
    height 250px

.use-class
    --custom-stroke-width 0
    --custom-duration .5s
    --custom-property all

.use-class:hover
    --custom-stroke-width 2
    --custom-stroke blue
    --custom-duration 2500ms
    --custom-property all
```

#### Expected behavior

When you hover the svg container, the values of the variables change and stroke `stroke-width 0` smoothly flows into `stroke-width 2` — this happens but without  `transition` although `transition` assigned to `<path>` this can be seen in 
[DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYoJi.jpg)

### Where does this work?

1. Inline svg through tag `<svg>` — `<svg> <path d="..."> </svg>`
2. Using tag `<object></object>` with external css

Demonstration can be seen on CodePen

> https://codepen.io/Cloudesign/pen/bLaEWg

---

**How to make `CSS transition` work for `external-svg-sprites`?** I'm tired of fighting this :(

Comment: CSS styles only apply to the document they are in. So the Applied CSS styles would need to be in the external document.

Comment: I didn't quite understand why you mentioned `CSS-style`, if `CSS-variables` seep through `<use>` and work properly.
**In addition, only `transition` does not work**, and all other `CSS-variables` work. Here that those not that, could you clarify your answer?

Comment: codepen works in **firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit)**, Does not work in Microsoft Edge 41.16

Answer (score 1):

> **update** As of September 2018, this still **does not work** everywhere except Firefox

Having carried out researches, it is revealed that this behavior is a **bug**.

At the moment on March 11, 2018 in the tested by me browsers under Windows 7, namely:

1. Chrome 64.0.3282.186 stable (64 bit)
2. Chrome 67.0.3368.0 canary (64 bit)
3. Vivaldi 1.14.1077.55 stable (32 bit)
4. Opera 51.0.2830.55 stable (64 bit)
5. Microsoft Edge 41.16 16 (undefine)

> **Does not work** and is an ERROR

*With the exception of*

1. **Firefox Version 60.0a1 nightly (64 bit)** *and in older versions* **58.0.2 (64 bit)**

[image]

I would be grateful to those who supplement information on the state of work in:

- Safari
- macOS
- others...